# css3 emulation in ie6 and others

Tags: css

Is there somewhere a one trick pony that just make all the nice feature of css3 (shadow, glow, round corner) and make it ie6 compatible /look alike...

[i have try that](http://ihisham.com/2010/04/css3-in-ie-6-7-and-8/)... oh boy it's ugly !...
i am looking more a javascript file ot something else

Comment: the pretty much answer everything.... but like your finding ...http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/

Comment: i have implement it to my website.. NOPE screw up everything !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the best thing I have find so far... but still dont get crazy about it
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 0):

You could try asking IE6 users to install [Chrome Frame](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started), but there's no perfect solution - sometimes you just have to accept that a 9 year old browser isn't going to support three year old standards.